# Cannot open SQL Server 2014 .bak file in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I'm uploading a `.bak` file I created on my hosting server, the hosting provider is using SQL Server 2014 or 2016 version. I download the file, but can't open in my SQL Server 2008. I got a message :

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

Comment: easiest solution is to use same or higher version of SQL Server. If your DB size is not huge, you can use SQL Server Express edition or SQL Server 2016 Developer. Both are free

Comment: so i must buy sql server 2015 version.. its hard hehehe

Comment: yes. it is hard to buy `SQL Server 2015`, as it is not exist. If you using it for development, you can use 2016 / 2017 developer edition, it is free :)

Answer (score 1):

I think You won't be able to do this. Upper version bak file can't be restored to lower version. The better option is to generate script of that database from 2008 R2 and run it to your desired version of sql server.

Comment: Correct - backup files are not backward-compatible.

Comment: how to generate script if the db in hosting server?

Comment: go through this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2500/sql-server-2008-r2-generate-scripts-wizard-with-database-schema-and-data/ . Hope you will get the idea